# How to make mount point in Solaris 10(installing Oracle RAC)?

Tags: oracle, mount, solaris-10

I want to install Oracle RAC on solaris 10, using ASM but I am new in it...

So I want to mount /u0 directory on the disk volume /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2

1) I have created /u0 directory by root user like this:

```
# mkdir /u0
```

2) I've added the following entries in .vsftab file:

```
 /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2  /u0    ufs    2      yes    -
```

For to make file system to mount automatically.

3) Then I have typed the following command, for to mount directory now:

```
mount /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2 /u0
```

Am I right???? Please, give me some advice how to mount directory on solaris and what steps should I make for to install oracle RAC on this system.

P.S. Step 3 gives me the following error:

```
mount: /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2 or /u0, no such file or directory
```

P.S2 Which Oracle should I download for to install RAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Check if Disk /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2 exists
you can use the format command to check
2.) If yes, does it have a ufs file system ?
You can refer to http://www.softpanorama.org/Solaris/Disks_and_filesystems/solaris_ufs.shtml

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you :) I do not have c2t0d0s2 but I have c2t1d0s2, unfortunately I didn't notice this mistake...
Because of I still need some help about how to install ORACLE RAC on solaris, I should not accept your answer...Still waiting...